# Adding two numbers of large length using strings

Tags: java, string

I can't seem to figure out what wrong with this method used to add two strings. It has a buffer when stores each added digit and finally displays. However when two huge numbers (greater than 10 digits) are added it just truncates and doesn't store the remainder of the string.

```
public static void add(String a,String b){
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    if((a.length() - 1==0)&&(a.charAt(0)=='0')){
        System.out.println(b);
        return;
    }
    if((b.length() - 1==0)&&(b.charAt(0)=='0')){
        System.out.println(a);
        return;
    }
    else{
    for ( int i1 = a.length() - 1, i2 = b.length() - 1, carry = 0;
          (i1 >= 0 && i2 >= 0) || carry != 0;i1--, i2-- ) {
        int digit1 = i1 < 0 ? 0 :
                     Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(a.charAt(i1)));
        int digit2 = i2 < 0 ? 0 :
                     Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(b.charAt(i2)));

        int digit = digit1 + digit2 + carry;
        if (digit > 9) {
            carry = 1;
            digit -= 10;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }

        buf.append(digit);
    }
   }
    System.out.println(buf.reverse().toString());
}
```

Comment: Change your variables from **int** to **long** should do the trick.

Comment: if you're into seeing how this should really be done checkout the sourcecode for BigInteger: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java

Comment: @jbutler483 `int` vs. `long` should not matter here. The loop is working on only two digits at a time (plus a possible carry) so it's never dealing with values above 19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since need to stop when both `i1` and `i2` reach a negative value, the condition should be

```
i1 >= 0 || i2 >= 0 || carry != 0
```

rather than

```
(i1 >= 0 && i2 >= 0) || carry != 0
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/swro1M)

Comment: Hey the problem still perists
try adding 497987965 and 13544

Comment: @AkhilBalaji Works perfectly for me ([link](http://ideone.com/7xCV3Q)). You must have forgotten to make `497987965` a `long` (the value does not fit in an `int`).

Answer (score 1):

Just use BigInteger, and your whole method is then three lines long.